# Removing duplicates from Linked List

Tags: c

Tried the linked list problem 1. from Cracking the coding interview here in cpp. 
-Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list.
FOLLOW UP
How would you solve this problem if a temporary buffer is not allowed?

What do you think of this implementation.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
struct node *tail = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

struct node* createNode(int data)
{
    struct node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    head = newNode;
    return newNode;
}

bool insertAfter(node * list, int data)
{
    //case 1 - insert after head
    struct node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (!list)
    {

        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        return true;
    }

    struct node * curpos = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curpos = head;
    //case 2- middle, tail of list
    while (curpos)
    {
        if (curpos == list)
        {
            newNode->data = data;
            if (curpos->next == NULL)
            {
                newNode->next = NULL;
                tail = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode->next = curpos->next;
            }
            curpos->next = newNode;
            return true;
        }
        curpos = curpos->next;
    }
}

void deleteNode(node *runner, node * curr){

    //DELETE AT TAIL
    if (runner->next->next == NULL)
    {
        runner->next = NULL;        
    }
    else//delete at middle
    {
        runner->next = runner->next->next;
    }
}


void removedups(node * list)
{
    struct node * curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    struct node * runner = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr = head;
    runner = curr;
    while (curr != NULL){
        runner = curr;
        while (runner->next != NULL){
            if (curr->data == runner->next->data){
                deleteNode(runner, curr);
            }
            if (runner->next!=NULL)
                runner = runner->next;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct node * list = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    list = createNode(1);
    insertAfter(list,2);
    insertAfter(list, 2);
    insertAfter(list, 3);   
    removedups(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `1.` You have memory leaks. `2.` This code will not remove duplicates if the same values are not following each other. `3.` Don't expect great results from that interview. `4.` Learn STL.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe take a look at STL's Set?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

Comment: using malloc in a c++ program will get you into trouble

Answer (score 2):

It looks more like C code, not C++.

If it's for an interview, try to use recursion, they ask linked list questions mainly to see if you are comfortable with it. Just to test if you are good with different kind of algorithms.

You have a lot of malloc (which is C style for dynamic memory allocation), but where do you free the memory?
Memory leaks are also something they want to **hear** you think about!
So don't hesitate to say it out loud: Now I have to check that I am not messing up the memory!